# Alertbox is displaying before searching the data

Tags: javascript, php

In the below code i am searching a data from mysql.And in this code without searching the data alert box is displaying when the code is executed.And Pls tell me whether i can place a table in alert box and how?

```
<?php  
$search = (isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : null);

  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") OR die (mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db ("slseatapp") or die(mysql_error());

  $query = "SELECT * FROM `coursemaster` WHERE `course_code` LIKE '%$search%' or `course_name` like '%$search%'";

  $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

   $msg ;
     if($result) 
     {    
        while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))   
       {      
            $msg=$msg ."ID=".$row[0].",COURSE CODE=".$row[1].",COURSE NAME=".$row[2];

       }   
        echo"<script>alert('$msg');</script>";  
     }
   else
     { 
       echo "No result";  
     }
 ?>

<form action="look.php" method="post">  
 <center> SEARCH:<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="SEARCH"><br></center>  
 <center> <input type="submit" name="hhhh" class="btn-success btn"></center>
</form>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM coursemaster WHERE course_code LIKE '%$search%' or course_name like '%$search%'"; use this.

Comment: It is working fine my problem is without searching the data it is displaying the alertbox

Answer (score 1):

> in this code without searching the data alert box is displaying when the code is executed.

Yes, you're assigning `$search` but never checking whether it's empty or not. You need an `if ($search !== '') { ... }` around all the code from `mysql_connect` to the end of the `?>` block, so that you only do a search when there's something to search for.

> It is working fine

Not really. You have SQL injection in your query creation (use `mysqli` or PDO parameterised statements instead of trying to create a query from user input yourself), and you have JavaScript injection (cross-site-scripting) in echoing a script block containing unescaped variable content (consider creating a results array and JSON-encoding it to pass it to JavaScript `JSON.parse()`). This is some way off being safe to deploy on the public internet.

> Pls tell me whether i can place a table in alert box

You cannot. `alert()` has minimal display capabilities and is generally considered bad for the user because, as a modal dialog box, it hangs up everything else in the browser until dismissed. `alert()` is useful for debugging, but for presenting data to the user you should use an in-page `<div>` containing whatever content you want.